# A question about Atoms in Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

By definition of an atom "For a measure space $(X,M,\mu)$, a set $A\in M$ is called an atom for $\mu$ if $\mu(A)>0$ and for any $B\in M$ with $B\subset A$ one has either $\mu(B) = 0$ or $\mu(B) = \mu(A)$."

Here's the question "$a = \inf\{\mu(E): E\in M \text{ with }\mu(E) > 0\}$ and $a$ is strictly positive. Show that there exist an atom $A\in M$ for $\mu$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ and for any $B\in M$ with $B \subset A$ one has either $\mu(B) = 0$ or $\mu(B) = \mu(A)$."

Need help on how to do this problem. Hint: if $E\in M$ is not an atom but has $\mu(E)>0$, show that there exist $F \subset E$ one has either $\mu(F) = 0$ or $\mu(F) = 0.5 \mu(E)$.

I'm able to prove this for a special case of $X$ with $\mu$ as Lebesgue Stieltjes measure associated to the increasing and right continuous function F but not with the given condition.

Sorry for some notational errors. I'm new to SE and still learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: What is the problem/question? The only thing I see is the definition of atom for a measure.

Comment: just edited the statement. thanks

Comment: So, the problem is “If $\inf\{\mu(E) : E \in \mathcal{M},\, \mu(E)>0\}$ is positive, then there is an atom for $\mu$”? If yes, why write it that way, and what does the hint have to do with it?

Comment: It has been given by the professor this way! I'm not able to use the condition or the hint in proving E as an atom. That's where I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu (A) =0$ or $\infty$ for all $A$ then the result is trivial. If that is not the case then we can restrict our attention to a set $A$ with $0 <\mu (A) <\infty$, so we may assume  that $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Observe that there is no set $E$ with $0 <\mu (E) <a$.  (1)

Suppose there is no atom. Then there exists $A_1\subseteq A$ such that $0<\mu(A_1)<\mu(A)$. By induction there exists a  seqeunce $(A_n)$ such that $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ and $0<\mu(A_{n+1})<\mu(A_n)$. Now $(A_n\setminus  A_{n+1})$ is a disjoint sequence so  $\sum \mu (A_n\setminus  A_{n+1})\leq \mu (A)<\infty$. But then $\mu (A_n\setminus  A_{n+1}) \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. But (1) shows that $\mu (A_n\setminus  A_{n+1})$ must be $0$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Since $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ this gives $\mu (A_{n+1})=\mu (A_n)$ contrary to our construction of $(A_n)$.

Comment: Hey thanks! I understood the first part where you took the disjoint seq but is it a decreasing seq bcz if it is only then its measure approaches to zero as n approaches to infinity? also, How does that we get no set  with 0<()<?

Comment: $A_n$ is not an atom so there exists $A_{n+1}$ as stated. Since $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ it follows that $(A_n)$ is decreasing. There is no set $E$ with $0 <\mu (E) <a$ by definition of $a$ as the infimum of all positive measures. @mathlearner

Comment: Does the last part goes like this? $\mu(/+1)=0$ which leads to (An)-(+1)=0 ?

Comment: @mathlearner Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.